# Django and CORS policy with multiple allowed hosts

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, cors

I have a small Django project running on a ubuntu server with NGINX and gunicorn.

Everything works great when users visit **www**.example.com, However, when a user visits example.com instead of www.example.com, this is where it falls apart. I am using some javascript with the fetch command, to get data from my API (Django REST) and it returns:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.example.com/builds/apidata/4' 
from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS 
policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 
'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The easiest solution I have found is to just remove example.com from my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in my `settings.py` file, but then when users forget `www.` they will be greeted with a 404 error.

The CORS error message also states I can change the request mode, but I don't know the security implications of this..

I also tried to use redirection on my domain settings from example.com to www.example.com, but this doesn't seem work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could certainly use CORS to allow this cross-domain usage, a simpler and cleaner solution is to just allow one root domain—either with `www` or not.

Setting [`PREPEND_WWW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-PREPEND_WWW) to `True` is a simple way to ensure that requests consistently use the `www` version, as it causes `CommonMiddleware` to issue redirects when the non-`www` version is used.

Answer (score 1):

In your webserver configuration, you can add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your www subdomain, which would allow requests from your root domain.

This would work: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`